# Unchecked or unsafe operations. array to JList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

Getting a warning "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" when I compile and if there are any warnings what so ever my university lecturer marks you down even if it doesn't affect anything.

```
public class Blah {
    JList listbox;

    public Blah {
        public String[] name = {"Joe", "John", "James"};
        doSomething(name);
    }

    private void doSomething(String[] itemArray) {
        if(itemArray != null) {
            listbox = new JList(itemArray);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the error comes up for the line `listbox = new JList(itemArray);` and I need to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Comment: `public String[] name.....` will give you IllegalstartOfExpression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a generics warning as `JList` now supports generics...

You should be able to get around it using

```
JList<String> listBox;
```

And

```
listbox = new JList<>(itemArray);
```

The intention is to ensure that the data you added to the `JList` meets with it's expectations of the `JList`.  It also can help reduce the need to cast from `Object` to whatever data type you might be expecting

Answer (score 0):

You should use generic types like this - (*use `String` , as you are going to have Strings is your list*)

```
JList<String> listbox;
listbox = new JList<String>(itemArray);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Comment: FYI "<>" instead of "<String>" can be used in your second statement (depending on java version).